# Why does ProvideFault catch my TimeoutExceptions?

Tags: wcf, timeoutexception, ierrorhandler

I've got a `ProvideFault()` service that communicates through wcf.  For most exceptions, we want to catch them, convert them into a `FaultException<CustomException>`, and let the caller handler it, so we've implemented `ProvideFault()`.

So far, so good, and it mostly works.  But this service is calling another service, which sometimes throws a `TimeoutExeption`; we don't want to catch that exception, but instead let it bubble up to the caller (or even throw a new `TimeoutException`, if necessary).  The problem is that when the method throws a `TimeoutException`, `ProvideFault()` tries to deal with it and turn it into a FaultException.

How do I force wcf to let it bubble up as a `TimeoutException`?

Answer (score 1):

WCF sends exceptions as FaultExceptions, so you cannot bubble up a Timeout Exception.

What you can do however is to send up a:

```
FaultException<TimeoutException>
```

Comment: But then I have to catch it as a FaultException<TimeoutException>.  The client already has handling from TimeoutException in place, and I was hoping not to change it.

Comment: You have to catch both. It can also be positive, since you are able to see where the timeout occured.